# nhibernate, could not resolve property QueryOver only one table

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have found a dozen of question similar to mine but none of them offered a solution to my problem.

Thank you in advance

Ok,

I have this class

```
public class User : IEntity
    {
        private int id;
        public virtual int Id { get { return id; } }


        private string email;

        public virtual string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            //private set { email = value; }
        }

        private string password;

        public virtual string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            //private set { password = value; }
        }

        private bool isActive;

        public virtual bool IsActive
        {
            get { return isActive; }
            //private set { isActive = value; }
        }

        private bool isRegistered;

        public virtual bool IsRegistered
        {
            get { return isRegistered; }
            //private set { isRegistered = value; }
        }

        private bool hasRequestedApplication;

        public virtual bool HasRequestedApplication
        {
            get { return hasRequestedApplication; }
            //private set { hasRequestedApplication = value; }
        }


        private ContactInfo contactInformation;

        public virtual ContactInfo ContactInformation
        {
            get { return contactInformation; }
            //private set { contactInformation = value; }
        }



        public User(string email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public User(string email, string password):this(email)
        {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public User()
        { }
}
```

this is the mapping....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain"
                 namespace="Domain.User" default-access="field">

  <class name="User" table="[User]">

    <id name="id" column="UserID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="email" column="Email" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="password" column="HashedPassword" not-null="false"></property>
    <property name="isRegistered" column="IsRegistered" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="isActive" column="IsActive" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="hasRequestedApplication" column="HasRequestedApplication" not-null="true"></property>

    <one-to-one name="contactInformation" class="Domain.User.ContactInfo"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is how i am calling it

```
 public class UserRepository: IUserRepository
    {
        Func<ISession> session;

        public UserRepository(Func<ISession> _session)
        {
            session = _session;
        }

        [Transaction]
        public User FindByEmail(string emailAddress)
        {
            using (var tx = session())
            {
                return tx.QueryOver<User>().Where(u => u.Email == emailAddress).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
}
```

Error...
{"could not resolve property: Email of: Domain.User.User"}

StackTrace...

at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.ToType(String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GetSubclassPropertyTableNumber(String propertyPath)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.ToColumns(String alias, String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.ToColumns(String alias, String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetColumns(ICriteria subcriteria, String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetColumnsUsingProjection(ICriteria subcriteria, String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Criterion.CriterionUtil.GetColumnNamesUsingPropertyName(ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, ICriteria criteria, String propertyName, Object value, ICriterion critertion)
   at NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression.ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetWhereCondition(IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker..ctor(IOuterJoinLoadable persister, CriteriaQueryTranslator translator, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, ICriteria criteria, String rootEntityName, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader..ctor(IOuterJoinLoadable persister, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, CriteriaImpl rootCriteria, String rootEntityName, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.UniqueResultT
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.SingleOrDefault()
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.NHibernate.IQueryOver.SingleOrDefault()
   at DataObjects.NHibernate.UserRepository.FindByEmail(String emailAddress) in E:\Projects\DataObjects.NHibernate\UserRepository.cs:line 26
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IUserRepository_FindByEmail.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.TransactionInterceptor.SynchronizedCase(IInvocation invocation, ITransaction transaction) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\9844bdf039249947\src\Castle.Facilities.AutoTx\TransactionInterceptor.cs:line 137

EDIT:

OK. Solved to some extent. I changed all my properties and components name to capital in my mapping.
Instead of...

```
<property name="email" column="emailaddress" />
```

set it to...

```
<property name="Email" column="emailaddress" />
```

and it works. Now, is that a guarantee that NHibernate is populating/reading my properties via the fields? I hope so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help: Change the settings to be different for *get* and *set*

```
<hibernate-mapping ... default-access="field.camelcase">
```

and map the properties:

```
<property name="Email" column="emailaddress" />
```

NHibernate will use field for set and the Property for get. This QueryOver:

```
return tx.QueryOver<User>()    
  .Where(u => u.Email == emailAddress)  
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

...will work now

Comment: Hello Radim, That's exactly what i did. It's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "name" of the properties in your mapping should match the case of the public virtual properties in your class. Try changing `<property name="email"...` to `<property name="Email"...` and so on.

Comment: I think the default value for the default-access attribute in the mapping is property, but mine says field. Is there a convenience to have it set to property and eliminate all private fields from my class?

Comment: @Tony - yes it is convenient to do auto-property mapping bypassing the field, however consider that [auto-properties can be a code smell](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/26/CodeSmellAutomaticProperty.aspx).

Comment: I definitely want to use field access because of Null Pattern i am planning to use. Also, the idea of auto-properties doesn't sound too good to my hears. I forgot to add that i am using a DDD approach to write my application, so domain objects with setters in their properties are a NO-NO.

Comment: You can still do private setters, NHibernate uses reflection so it will work either way.